# Container killed on request. Exit code is 137" errors in Spark on Amazon EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

We have spark job which randomly fails.

Code is pretty simple :

1. load 2 dataframes from SqlServer
2. join them
3. write the result to Mysql

Total data size is around 10.2 GB.

configuration details :

`Master:1 r4.8xlarge`

`Slave:4 r4.4xlarge`

```
                            "spark.driver.memory": "57.6G",
                            "spark.driver.cores": "5",
                            "spark.driver.memoryOverhead": "25600",

                            "spark.executor.memory": "54G",
                            "spark.executor.cores": "5",
                            "spark.executor.memoryOverhead": "6144",

                            "spark.executor.instances": "8",
                            "spark.default.parallelism": "112",
                            "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions": "-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+PrintReferenceGC -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+G1SummarizeConcMark -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:ConcGCThread=20",
                            "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "false"
```

It's really difficult to understand this behavior, when it fails it's always the same error :

`ERROR : Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 54 in stage 12.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 54.3 in stage 12.0 (TID 1011, ip-10-43-67-156.hrlogix.va, executor 111): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 111 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container marked as failed: container_1591579744421_0001_01_000124 on host: ip-10-43-67-156.hrlogix.va. Exit status: 137. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 137
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 137
Killed by external signal.`

We have already tried playing around incresing executor-memory ,driver-memory, spark.sql.shuffle.partitions & df.repartition as mentioned in

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/container-killed-on-request-137-emr/

Can anyone help ?

Comment: can you post code if possible ??

Comment: @Srinivas code looks like
`parentTableDF = Utility.importFromSqlServer(sourceDBURL, sourceDBUser, sourceDBPass, tableName, sqlContext)`

`val pushDownSourceTableQuery = s"(SELECT * FROM $sourceTable WHERE ClientID = $sourceClientID) a"`

`childTableDF = Utility.importFromSqlServer(sourceDBURL, sourceDBUser,sourceDBPass, pushDownSourceTableQuery, sqlContext)`

`destinationTableDF = parentTableDF.join(childTableDF, 'col1')`

`Utility.importFromMysqlTable(destinationDBURL, destinationDBUser, destinationDBPass, destinationTableDF, sqlContext)`